# Add a custom column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have a query...

```
qry = Query(models.UserList).filter(...)
```

`models.UserList` contains a mixin method that will return a `count` of a related table

So what I would like to do is something like ...

```
qry = qry.order_by(models.UserList.contactCount)
```

However this produces invalid sql of course.

So how can I do something like

```
qry.add_column((this.contactCount).label("contactCount"))
```

`this.contactCount` is just bad psuedocode, but hopefully you get the point.

I've been looking at how to do this for a while, but sqlalchemy doc isnt the easiest thing to find stuff in.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a `column_property` or a `hybrid_property` for that. For example:

```
class UserList(Base):
    ...
    contactCount = column_property(
        select(
            [func.count()],
            contact_id == Contact.id,
        ).label('contactCount'),
        deferred=True,
    )
```

Comment: flip, I think this would've worked had we not had SQLALchemy v 0.3 installed (5yrs ago?) -_-.  may ask the team if we can upgrade it.  ill mark this as the answer anyway as I came across it in the docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

Comment: Ouch.. my own upgrade policy for SQLAlchemy is always "latest == greatest" :)